# Javascript - Finding Pizza winner out of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string-comparison

Any customer that orders a three-topping pizza with a unique combination of
toppings across all pizzas in all stores for that month will receive a coupon for a free pizza by email (if they provide their email address).

Here are two methods for finding out the winner. But none of these methods is working properly. I am not sure where the bug is. Also which dataset should I use to test these implementations? How can I solve this problem with database queries?

```js
// Here is the json array and functions:
const inputArray = [{"email": "email1@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
    {"email": "email2@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Cheddar","Garlic","Oregano"]},
    {"email": "email3@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Parmesan","Tomatoes"]},
    {"email": "email4@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Cheddar","Tomatoes"]},
    {"email": "email5@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
    {"email": "email6@example.com", "toppings": ["Beef","Parmesan"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Onions","Pepperoni"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]}]


function printWinners1(inputArray) {
  // Perform a QuickSort on the array.
  inputArray.sort((a, b) => {
    // Convert each toppings array to a string and do a string comparison
    return a.toppings.toString().localeCompare(b.toppings.toString());
  });
  let previousEmail = '';
  let previousToppingsAsString = '';
  let previousToppingCount = 0;
  let numberOfSimilarOrders = 0;
  // Iterate through the array, with "order" being each item in the  array.
  inputArray.map((order) => {
    let toppingsAsString = order.toppings.toString();
    if (toppingsAsString === previousToppingsAsString) {
      numberOfSimilarOrders++;
    } else {
      if ((numberOfSimilarOrders === 1) && 
          (previousToppingCount === 3) && 
          (previousEmail) !== '') {
        // Print out the email.
        console.log(previousEmail);
      }
      previousToppingsAsString = toppingsAsString;
      previousEmail = order.email;
      previousToppingCount = order.toppings.length;
      numberOfSimilarOrders = 1;
    }
  });
}

function printWinners2(inputArray) {
  let hashTable = new Map();
  // Iterate through the array, with "order" being each item in the array.
  inputArray.map((order) => {
    if ((order.toppings.length === 3) && (order.email !== '')) {
      let toppingsAsString = order.toppings.toString();
      let matchingValue = hashTable.get(toppingsAsString);
      if (matchingValue) {
        // This key was already in the hash table.
        // matchingValue is a reference to the object in the hash table.
        matchingValue.duplicate = true;
      } else {
        // Insert into the hash table, using the toppings as the           key and an object containing the email as the value.
        hashTable.set(toppingsAsString, {
          email: order.email,
          duplicate: false
        });
      }
    }
  });
  // Iterate through the values in the hash table, with "value" being each value.
  hashTable.forEach((value) => {
    if (!value.duplicate) {
      // Print out the email.
      console.log(value.email);
    }
  });
}
printWinners1(inputArray)
```

Comment: you ask about database queries.. what kind of database are you running? Also what are the exact criteria for winning? Just has ordered and also has an email on file?

Comment: who is the winner here? please provide some more info on how to calculate the winner,  may be with some expected output.

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Next time try to format the code in a snippet `[<>]`

Comment: I want to load this JSON data and print out the email addresses of any winners. (For the above example, it would print out
email2@example.com.)
REASON: This is the winner because He selected 3 toppings Cheddar","Garlic","Oregano these are unique among all other toppings and he provided his email address and no less than 3 topping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my take on it.

I go through your order list and rearrange it in an object ("hash") according to the chosen topping triplets. The toppings are sorted to make the order in which they are mentioned irrelevant.

I then filter through them again a to check for their uniqueness. The output is an array of arrays: each sub-array contains the topping combination followed by a one-item-array of emails of winners.

```js
const inputArray = [{"email": "email1@example.com", "toppings":
["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
{"email": "email2@example.com", "toppings":
["Cheddar","Garlic","Oregano"]},
{"email": "email3@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
{"email": "", "toppings": ["Parmesan","Tomatoes"]},
{"email": "email4@example.com", "toppings":
["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
{"email": "", "toppings": ["Cheddar","Tomatoes"]},
{"email": "email5@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
{"email": "email6@example.com", "toppings": ["Beef","Parmesan"]},
{"email": "", "toppings": ["Onions","Pepperoni"]},
{"email": "", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]}];

var win=Object.entries(inputArray.reduce((a,c)=>{
  if (c.toppings.length==3){
let top=c.toppings.sort().join('_');
if (c.email) (a[top]=a[top]||[]).push(c.email);
  }
  return a;
}, {})).filter(([t,m])=>m.length==1);

console.log(win);
// The actual list of winners is extracted like this:
console.log(win.map(c=>c[1][0]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I am messing around with it now on jsfiddle to see if i can make something get your results. The first thing jumping out at me is that you have the below:

```
inputArray.sort((a, b) => {
    // Convert each toppings array to a string and do a string comparison
    return a.toppings.toString().localeCompare(b.toppings.toString());
  });
```

The sort array is not mutating which means it returns the sorted array, you would need to catch that in a variable.

```
let sortedArray = inputArray.sort((a, b) => {
    // Convert each toppings array to a string and do a string comparison
    return a.toppings.toString().localeCompare(b.toppings.toString());
  });
```

*Edit

Ok my solution was a bit more stepped and explicit so you can visualize each step and what's happening. I tried to structure it similar to what you had as far as process goes to keep in line with your original intentions.

https://jsfiddle.net/goofballtech/khv873ef/3/

```
function printWinners(){

// filter array down to email addresses and 3 topping pizza's
  let onlyEmails = orders.filter(order => order.email && order.toppings.length === 3)

// change orders to have sorted toppings and add a place to track similar order, then sort the entire list by order toppings
  let toppingsAsStrings = onlyEmails.map(order => {
    return {
      email: order.email,
      toppings: order.toppings.sort().toString(),
      similarOrders: 0,
    }
  }).sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.toppings.toLowerCase() < b.toppings.toLowerCase()) {
      return -1
    } else if (a.toppings.toLowerCase() > b.toppings.toLowerCase()) {
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  })

  // check each order against it neighbors marking it if two of them match
 for (let i = 0; i < toppingsAsStrings.length; i++){
    if (i == 0) {
      toppingsAsStrings[i].toppings === toppingsAsStrings[i + 1].toppings ? toppingsAsStrings[i].similarOrders = 1 : null
    } else if (i == toppingsAsStrings.length - 1) {
      toppingsAsStrings[i].toppings === toppingsAsStrings[i - 1].toppings ? toppingsAsStrings[i].similarOrders = 1 : null
    } else {
      toppingsAsStrings[i].toppings === toppingsAsStrings[i + 1].toppings ||
        toppingsAsStrings[i].toppings === toppingsAsStrings[i - 1].toppings ?
        toppingsAsStrings[i].similarOrders = 1 :
        null
    }
  }

//find the ones that did not have matches
  let winners = toppingsAsStrings.filter(order => !order.similarOrders)

  console.log(winners)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work!!!

I've checked 4 conditions here:

1. email must not be empty.
2. length of toppings must be three.
3. No duplicates to be there in Result array.
4. unique check for toppings

```js
var inputArray = [{"email": "email1@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
    {"email": "email2@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Cheddar","Garlic","Oregano"]},
    {"email": "email3@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Parmesan","Tomatoes"]},
    {"email": "email4@example.com", "toppings":
    ["Mushrooms","Pepperoni","Peppers"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Cheddar","Tomatoes"]},
    {"email": "email5@example.com", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]},
    {"email": "email6@example.com", "toppings": ["Beef","Parmesan"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Onions","Pepperoni"]},
    {"email": "", "toppings": ["Bacon","Ham","Pineapple"]}];

function printWinners(inputArr) {
    var res = [];
    for(var i= 0; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
        if(inputArr[i]['email'] !== '' && inputArr[i]['toppings'].length === 3 && !res.find(item => item['email'] === inputArr[i]['email']) && (new Set(inputArr)).size === inputArr.length) {
            res.push(inputArr[i]);
      }

    }
    return res;
}

console.log(printWinners(inputArray));
```